# Changing Angular template structure on the fly

Tags: angularjs, templates, dynamic

I am creating a schedule of events for a festival and the way the events are presented need to follow two different layouts with some similarities. Is it possible to have an angular template that could cater to both layouts? I hope this simple image makes sense what I need to do. Basically I have two batches of data to go on the same page one at a time. Take a look at this link to see one of the layouts in action: http://roobp.com/2015-FOB-Real/
 [image: multiple angular layouts]

Comment: to clarify the problem, if you look at the link I posted, half the events need to just show author: title, while the other half have different info to show such as moderator etc. plz let me know if further clarification is needed. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by layouts?.. you can do this sort of stuff in `router`... but your use case isn't very clear.

Comment: ok I get it .. but is there some condition on which you decide which template to use?

Comment: This is far too vague to figure out what specific issue is. Maybe showing as sample data would help to understand. The relationships between data and view are probably the main issue

Comment: @-charlietfl please see this page: http://roobp.com/2015-FOB-Real/   this sample page is layed out with author:title at the center. For half of the data the center needs to change to moderator: author format.
@Minato the changing condition would be the venue. There are two kinds of venues, each of which would display the participants differently.
Any thoughts?

Comment: to be real specific: the deciding condition is the venue, meaning selecting certain venues will load Template A while other venues will load or display Template B. Perhaps applying an ng-class toggling display:none would work? if so how would that be scripted in controller.js?

Comment: @roob have a look at this. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mubashirhanif/xrzjs8a8/2/)

Comment: @roob for your case [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mubashirhanif/xrzjs8a8/3/)

Comment: @Minato awesome, thank you! I am almost there with my problem, if I may direct you to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/roob/oLhr2ser/38/
The only problem left to figure is if you look in the view in the drop menu where it says "All Venues", when All is selected nothing shows, but when you make a selection the relevant data is pulled in correctly. Basically how to have the default to show all the data?
Sorry that the fiddle is complex, this is only a sample of the bigger application with hundreds of entries.

Comment: @Minato I simplified the fiddle a little and added some comments, hope to make it clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/roob/oLhr2ser/40/  thanks in advance

Comment: ng-switch portion in the html begins at line 41

Comment: @roob The problem with your code is that you still don't have a clear difference between when to use which template...

Comment: @Minato Yes I caught a mistake, sorry: https://jsfiddle.net/roob/oLhr2ser/42/ 
Look at line 6 and 7 where value is either stage or panel. When a stage is selected then data is displayed in one way; when panel is selected the second set is displayed. So that functionality is now working, what does not work is the default of showing everything in the view, ie I need to have everything to show when "All Venues" is selected from the select menu.

Comment: @roob that's the issue.. You need to specify the criteria when and what Template should be used... currently you are depending on the criteria given by the user... but you need to identify for example if the current artist has **x property** I'll use *Template A*, when artist has **y property** I'll use *Template B*

Comment: The only 2 criteria available are stage or panel, I'm not sure what else to set here - sorry I have not been using angular for long. It seems ng-switch was nicely doing the job except for setting a default of 'Show All'. Let me know if I am understanding your explanation. Do I need to write a function in controller perhaps?